# How to pass ant parameters to junit/selenium tests?

Tags: java, ant, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, junit4

Before i ask my question let me say, i've read through these related questions:

- [How do I pass an argument to an Ant task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911536/how-do-i-pass-an-argument-to-an-ant-task)
- [How do I pass parameters to a Junit test from Ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777000/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-a-junit-test-from-ant)

Here is what i'm looking to accomplish:

1. call ant script like:  `ant -Dhost="ip addy" -Dbrowser="chrome"`
2. in the ant script set the properties to arg1 and arg2
3. in the webdriver test call, `System.getProperty("key");` and use those values set to determine what Driver is loaded.

here is what i have right now:

from build.xml

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<!-- TARGET: Run JUNIT Tests  depends on remove and compile-->

    <target name="junit" depends="remove,compile">
        <!-- remove junit dir -->
        <delete dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <!-- make junit dir -->
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
            <sysproperty key="host" value="${arg1}"/>
            <sysproperty key="browser" value="${arg2}"/>
            <test name="${test.dir}.TestMyTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            //.......
```

java code in setup():

```
if (System.getProperty("browser").equals("firefox")) {
    log.logInfo("Firefox driver initialized");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
} else if (System.getProperty("browser").equals("ie") //....
```

When i execute `ant -Dhost=ip -Dbrowser=firefox` i am getting NPE's. I assume it has to do with my build script and setting those properties. I am under the impression i set this wrong.

```
[junit] Testcase: testMyTest took 0.001 sec
[junit]     Caused an ERROR
[junit] null
[junit] java.lang.NullPointerException
[junit]     at tests.TestMyTest.setUp(Unknown Source)
[junit]
```

My assumption here is `System.getProperty("browser")` is return null.  Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Show us how you set `arg1` and arg2`

Comment: I am trying to take the parameters from the ant command: ant param1 param2 and use those as ${arg1} or ${arg2} at this point, the code above is the only place $arg1 exists.

Comment: The Ant output shows `Unknown Source` as the origin of the NullPointerException. This means debugging information isn't being added to the TestMyTest.class file. In the `<javac>` task that compiles your test case, please add the following attribute: `debuglevel="lines,vars,source"`. Re-compile TestMyTest with Ant and update your post to reflect the new output.

Comment: The null pointer is occurring during run time. Its failing to get the system.getProperty(browser). that call is returning null.  The javac task already has that info in it, but compile completes w/o error.

Comment: <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeAntRuntime="false"/>

Comment: compile:
[delete] Deleting directory /Users/<user>/automation/build
[mkdir] Created dir:  /Users/<user>/automation/build/classes
[javac] Compiling 29 source files to /Users/<user>/automation/build/build/classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no properties named `arg1` and `arg2`. Instead, refer to the user properties by name:

```
<!-- Verify the properties exist. -->
<fail unless="host"/>
<fail unless="browser"/>

<junit fork="yes">
    <!-- ... -->
    <sysproperty key="host" value="${host}"/>
    <sysproperty key="browser" value="${browser}"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</junit>
```

Comment: Chad, thanks for the tips, however i am still getting null values when i try to retrieve the property in the java code.                               String browser = sys.getProperty("browser");
String host = sys.getProperty("host");
log.logInfo("The browser system property is set to: " + browser);
log.logInfo("The host system property is set to: " + host);`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my own coding mistake along with the help from @Chad Nouis it is now resolved.

```
Properties sys = new Properties();
```

should have been:

```
Properties sys = System.getProperties();
```

Chad Thanks again for your help!